# Find $a_{2020}$ in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_n=(n-1)(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$ what is the value of $a_{2020}$?

I have tried some methods that were applied to the Fibonacci sequence, but don't seem to work this time.

Comment: Try generating functions. It's almost the same as the one used for derangements, only there $a_1=0$ instead.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Actually, I don't know, my friend asked me this. Which contest are you about?

Comment: Contests often have questions featuring the year number so the $2020$ is suspicious.  It it were $2019$ or less then at least it would be a past paper for practice.

Comment: @badjohn Yeah, nice logic :)

Comment: Use generating functions. Solution is $a_n = n! - d_n$ where $d_n$ is the number of derangements of $n$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could use that $a_{n}=n\cdot a_{n-1} + (-1)^{n-1}$, which you could show by induction.. This recursion is the same as for [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), but there we have initial values $a_1=0, a_2=1$ instead.

So order of magnitude is about $n!$. A simple Python program will give you exact answer in less than a second...

Comment: Sorry, but what is $d$?

Comment: $d \to a$ sorry. Because it is the derangements recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be very simple if you use a Python algorithm, in particular:

```
a_nm2 = 1
a_nm1 = 1

for n in range(3,2021):

a_n = (n - 1) * (a_nm1 + a_nm2)

a_nm2 = a_nm1
a_nm1 = a_n

print("The 2020th term is:\n",a_n)
```

The result occupies several lines:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=n!\, b_n$ to make
$$n\, b_n=(n-1)\, b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$$ which is satisfied if $b_n$ is a constant.

For the second solution, I am stuck.

It seems to be sequence $A002467$ in $OEIS$.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the sequence [OEIS A002467](https://oeis.org/A002467), as can be proven by showing they have the same initial conditions and the same recurrence formula.

Comment: @awllower. I did want to introduce the subfactorial function. Because the exact solution involves it.